# Marionette view's Handlebars template compiled once before use

Tags: templates, backbone.js, marionette

I'm using Handlebars templating with a Marionette.CompositeView. The template is defined as:

```
template : function (serializedData) {
    var templFn = Handlebars.compile(myTemplateDef);
    return this.templFn(serializedData);
}
```

In traditional Backbone with Handlebars it is suggested to not compile the template each time we render the view, but instead to store the compiled template as a View property so it only gets compiled once thus saving on resources:

```
templFn : Handlebars.compile(myTemplateDef),

render : function () {
  var serializedData = this.model.toJSON();
  ...
  this.$el.append(this.templFn(serializedData);
}
```

But in the Marionette case the context of template() is `window` and I don't control how/when template() is called.

So the question is: given that we don't want to create a global var `window.templFn` is there a way to separate the template compilation from its usage in the case of Marionette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a handlebars plugin for marionette: https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Marionette.Handlebars

It may not be entirely up to date, but you should at least be able to see how they are handling the compilation of templates.

In general, Marionette provides a `Marionette.Renderer` and `Marionette.TemplateCache` object to allow a template to be compiled once, and only once, and then re-rendered from that cached template compilation.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I just started working with Marionette just 2 days ago, and I use Handlebars in my code before marionette ( pure backbone ), then I used this way in marionette :

```
template : function(data) {
  if (typeof this.tplFun === 'undefined') {
    this.tplFun = Handlebars.compile($('#angry_cat-handlebars').html());
  }
  return this.tplFun(data);
};
```

or you can just add tplFun into your initialize function